# C++ Are the following functions usable on windows/ non-windows platforms?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, function

**A: Is it correct that I can use those on *non-windows* platforms AND *windows* platforms?**

- _wfindfirst,
- _wsplitpath_s,
- _wmakepath_s

**B: Is it correct that I can use those on *windows* platforms ONLY ?**

- GetModuleFileName,
- GetFileVersionInfoSizeA, GetFileVersionInfoSizeW,
- GetFileVersionInfoA, GetFileVersionInfoW,
- VerQueryValueA, VerQueryValueW,
- LoadStringA, LoadStringW,
- GetAsyncKeyState

Comment: Any function name beginning with an underscore is non-standard, and can't be relied on to exist on any other system.

Comment: Also, all standard C++ functions are declared in the `std` namespace. And contains only lower-case letters. If a function is not in the `std` namespace, or have upper-case letters in their name, it's not a standard C++ name.